# JPEG: Conversion RGB to YCbCr and Sample Precision

Tags: image, jpeg

The [JPEG File Interchange Format Documentation](http://www.jpeg.org/public/jfif.pdf) gives formulae for converting RGB to YCbCr and vise versa.

One Formula is:

```
Cb = -0.1687*R - 0.3313*G + 0.5*B + 128
```

I was wondering why the `+ 128` and found out that this is for 8 Bit values for R, G and B (I hope that is correct).

But in another book I have found:

> The range of values for a color component is determined by the sample precision, which is the number of bits used to represent a component. For photographic images, 8 is the most common used sample precision. However, 1, 2, 4, 12, and 16 are also common.

The author also gives a formula vor Cb which is:

```
Cb = -0.1687*R - 0.3313*G + 0.5*B + 2^(Sample Precision/2)
```

Which for 8 Bit yields `+ 16`.

So there are two different values to add, both with 8 Bit values. Is the authors formula wrong or am I not unterstanding it correctly?

I would have expetec the formula to be like:

```
Cb = -0.1687*R - 0.3313*G + 0.5*B + 2^(Sample Precision)-1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are talking about different things. 1, 2, 4, 12, 16 bit precisions are common but not with JPEG (8 or 12).

I think there is a typo. Should be 2^(Sample Precision-1) or 2^Sample Precision/2 (the same). This is always going to be 128 for JPEG. I am only aware of 12-bit jpeg being used in one-component medical images (no conversion).

Your answer is add 128.